# Partial derivative of vector valued function with respect to a vector

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $G: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ be a vector-valued function defined by $G = (g_1, g_2, \dotsc , g_m$), where $g_i: \mathbb{R}^m \times \mathbb{R}^k \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Let the arguments be given by $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^m$ so that we can write

\begin{align*}
G(x,y) = (g_1(x,y), g_2(x,y), \dotsc, g_m(x,y)).
\end{align*}

Is it true that the partial derivative of $G$ with respect to $y$ is given by:

\begin{align*}
D_yG(x,y) = (D_yg_1(x,y), D_yg_2(x,y), \dotsc, D_yg_m(x,y))?
\end{align*}

Furthermore, what is the partial derivative of $g_i$ with respect to $y$?, that is
\begin{align*}
D_yg_i(x,y) = ?
\end{align*}

Comment: Yes, the formula is correct. We differentiate component-wise. As to your second question: It's just the second part of the gradient, hence the collection of the partials $D_yg_i = (\partial_{y_1}g_i,\ldots,\partial_{y_k}g_i)$.

Comment: Great! Thank you.